# Grails Transaction in Quartz Job

Tags: spring, grails, transactions

Good afternoon guys.

I have a question about the transactions until the spring and Grails own when I have multiple jobs running the same service.

I have a service with a default configuration in Grails and a method that runs every 5 sec. by the quartz job, but the execution of the method takes longer than 5 sec. to be completed. My question is when will the quartz calling this method they are executed in the same transaction or a new one is created each time this happens? I know that each invocation of quartz creates a new thread, but do not know if they are within the same transaction and for example if a call it will give an exception to rollback everything that has been done so far.

I appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction state is stored in ThreadLocals, so two concurrent transactional service calls on different threads would each have their own transactions.